# Extracting database table names from XML file

Tags: bash, unix, awk, sed, grep

I am trying to extract the schema and table name from an sql query inside an xml tag

Sample

```
<head>
<sql> select 1 from owner_a.table1 </sql>
<sql> select 1 from owner_b.table2 , owner_b.table3 where ... </sql>
<sql> select 1 from owner_c.table4 join owner_c.table5 on ... left join owner_c.table 6 on .. </sql>
<head>
```

As you may notice, the sql maybe in different format. 
- may or may not be in ANSI 
- may or may not contain where clause

the schema and table name does not have a specific pattern as well.

To extract the sql from the xml file, I used xml_grep.

```
xlm_grep 'sql' --text_only $file.xml
```

The next challenge and the part where I'm stuck is to get the schema and table name in this output

```
schema  | table_name
owner_a | table1
owner_b | table2
owner_b | table3
owner_c | table4
owner_c | table5
owner_c | table6
```

the approach I'm thinking  -- 
for non-ansi queries is to 
- get the string after the word "from" until "where" 
- split the string using comma as delimiter
- split again using "." as delimiter to separate the schema and table name

for ansi queries 
- get the string after the word "join" 
- split using "." as delimiter

is this the most efficient way to do this? is this doable using grep , sed or awk?

Comment: If you can list all the possibilities and find a pattern, then it can be done.  The challenge is to make sure you have all possibilities listed.  As for the output, this is trivial compared to the data extraction.

Comment: for now that would be all the possible query formats.

Comment: So you plan seems logical.  Start implementing :)

Comment: @user2058738, what are the sample input and sample output?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your SQL have space before and after table name.

Try

```
grep -o ' [a-z_]*\.[^ ]*'
```

Demo:

```
$cat file1.txt 
<head>
<sql> select 1 from owner_a.table1 </sql>
<sql> select 1 from owner_b.table2 , owner_b.table3 where ... </sql>
<sql> select 1 from owner_c.table4 join owner_c.table5 on ... left join owner_c.table 6 on .. </sql>
<head>
$grep -o ' [a-z_]*\.[^ ]*' file1.txt  | tr '.' '|' 
 owner_a|table1
 owner_b|table2
 owner_b|table3
 |||
 owner_c|table4
 owner_c|table5
 |||
 owner_c|table
 ||
$
```